# Numerictextbox kendo give by 0?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo numerictextbox, like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
              .Name("SignalThreshold")
              .Value(0)
              .Step(10)
              .Min(0)
              .Events(e => e.Change("FilterThresholdChange"))
              .Format("##.00")
```

but if the value is 0, then it displays: ????

How to resolve this?

Thank you

And this is the javascript:

```
var inpbox = $('#SignalThreshold').data("kendoNumericTextBox");

inpbox.setOptions(
                {
                    format: "\\" + label + "\\#",
                    decimals: 2,
                });
inpbox.value(inpbox.value());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved

```
inpbox.setOptions(
                {
                    round: true,
                    decimals: 0,


                });
```